# Como surgiu o uso da palavra “bem” no lugar de “muito”, i.e. “bem grande”?

Tags: significado, etimologia

Sendo um visitante no Brasil e um aluno da língua portuguesa, reparei que muita gente me chamava de "bem grande". Ao perguntar e aprender, descobri que tinha o mesmo sentido da palavra "muito".

Porquê?

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta "bem" interessante mesmo.

Comment: E me deixa confuso por vários anos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Me parece que este significado é antigo e vem do latim.

De acordo com o [Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/bem), a palvra "bem" vem do latim "bene".

De acordo com [*A Latin Dictionary*, por Charlton T. Lewis e Charles Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dbene) (em inglês), um dos significados da palavra bĕnĕ no latim era:

> **II.** *Adv. of intensity,* = valde, *very,* with *adjj.* and *advv.* …

Quer dizer

> Um advérbio de intensidade, equivalente a "valde", significando *muito*, que pode modificar um adjectivo ou um verbo

Acho que é mais provável que este uso da palavra *bem* passou do latim para o português.

---

<sub>Acho que seria possível, sempre que uma língua tem uma palavra que significa "boa qualidade", que esta palavra seja utilizada para significar "muita 'quantidade' de uma certa qualidade". Mas não sou linguista.</sub>

Comment: Boa explicação -- gostei!

Answer (score 3):

Andei à procura de *bem grande, bem pequeno*, etc. neste [Corpus do Português](http://corpus.byu.edu/), e encontrei-os desde que existem textos substanciais em português. Isto dá crédito à sugestão do Dan Getz (ver a resposta dele) que este uso de *bem* na aceção de *muito* esteve presente continuamente na evolução do latim ao português. Se por acaso se perdeu, no desenvolvimento do português ou do castelhano, foi readotado bem cedo nas duas línguas. Eis uma passagem da versão portuguesa das [*Sete Partidas de Afonso X*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siete_Partidas) de cerca de 1300:

> E por ende deue a enpolha en que see ou esta o olio pera ffazer a crisma deue seer cuberta de pano de sirgo ou de linho ***bë brãco*** o mays fremosso que poderë auer.
>
> Em português moderno: E por isso deve a ampola em que é ou está o óleo para fazer a crisma deve ser coberta de pano de seda ou de linho ***bem branco*** o mais formoso que poderem haver.

Passagem da [*Crónica Geral de Espanha*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_Geral_de_Espanha_de_1344) compilada em 1344 por Pedro Afonso, conde de Barcelos e filho natural de D. Dinis:

> E este rey don Sancho entrou a correr Castella que era del rey dom Afonso, seu sobrinho, e chegou ***bem perto*** de Burgos, ca com grande orgulho deu hûa grande cuitelada em hûû ulmo que estava ante a egreja de Sam Joham de Burgos.

Mais uns exemplos:

> Antenor diso a el rrey Príamo así: – Señor, as pleitesías que os gregos demãdam et querem son estas: querë que lles dedes d'aquí ata X ãnos, cada ãno çem mil marcos de bõo ouro fino et esquimado, et çem mil marcos de prata bë pesada et ***bë fina***, et çë mill carregas de pam. [(Crónica Troiana, 1388.)](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_troiana)
>
> "Senhor, bem sabees a rrazom por que eu fui fora d'este rreino no tempo d'elrrei dom Affonsso vosso avoo, seendo vós entom moço ***bem pequeno***, e isso meesmo ho aspero geito que elrrei dom Pedro vosso padre contra mim teve [(Fernão Lopes, Crónica de el-rei D. Fernando, c. 1434-51.)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern%C3%A3o_Lopes)
>
> hûa uez em montemor se ordenou tal cousa que se pasara fora ***bem grande*** agrauo aos fidalgos contra suas liberdades antigas. [(Chartularium Universitatis Portugalensis vol. 3 (1400) 1420-60.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=JL_IU1hpmsIC&pg=RA2-PA149&lpg=RA2-PA149&dq=ordenou%20tal%20cousa%20que%20se%20pasara%20fora&source=bl&ots=9diu_WVtjG&sig=S669nuSvH8c9wL2jxndQRR7nQ6c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQlqyEz_rJAhWIOxoKHa75AAUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=ordenou%20tal%20cousa%20que%20se%20pasara%20fora&f=false)

Comment: "Ende" significa mais ou menos o mesmo que o _en_ em francês. Vê o Aulete ou o Priberan ou o DRAE para castelhano. "Enpolha" é provavelmente de facto "ampola" (o Houaiss data ampola de 1330 e regista a variante "empola"; "enpola" aparece com o mesmo significado no mesmo texto). Acho que _see_ é forma do verbo _seer_ no sentido de _estar_, como descrito [aqui](http://www.letras.puc-rio.br/unidades&nucleos/catedra/revista/9Sem_02.html). Fica por esclarecer por que _deve_ está repetido.

Comment: @Artefacto Revi a 'tradução'. Também pensei que *see* pudesse ser uma forma do verbo *seer* (que aparece logo à frente). Mas fica estranho «ampola em que é ou está o óleo». A repetição do *deve* é estranha, mas não vejo que outra coisa possa ser. Possivelmente um deslize.

Comment: Adorei a resposa, e obrigado pela pesquisa!