# Qual a origem da palavra "tampouco"?

Tags: ortografia, português-brasileiro

*Tampouco* é advérbio, possui o mesmo sentido de "também não". Por exemplo:

> Você não quer ir ao cinema, eu tampouco.

Já *tão pouco* significa “muito pouco” refere-se à medida de tempo. Por exemplo:

> Faz tão pouco tempo que estou aqui.

Acho estranha a grafia da palavra *tampouco*.

Qual origem desta palavra?

Por que é escrita assim?

Comment: De referir que em Portugal não se usa muito, acho que se usava mais em tempos antigos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Significado

De acordo com o dicionário, *tampouco* não é sinônimo de *tão pouco*, mas sim [*tão-pouco*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/t%C3%A3o-pouco).

É uma maneira de negar *também = tão + bem*. Mesmo que [*bem* significa "muito"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/134/112) como advérbio de intensidade, [*pouco* como advérbio significa "não muito"](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/pouco). Compare:

> Estou bem feliz.
>
> Estou pouco feliz.
>
> Estou feliz, e ela também.
>
> Não estou feliz, e ela tampouco.

## Grafia

Esta grafia segue um padrão de português, não é uma excepção.

Se escrevem:

- *s**ão*** e *s**an**ta*, não **s**ão**ta*
- *irm**ão*** e *irm**an**dade*, não **irm**ão**dade*
- *t**ão***, *t**am**bém* e *t**am**pouco*, não **t**ão**bém* nem  **t**ão**pouco*

Quase sempre, `ão`, `ã`, `õe` e `ãe` aparece numa palavra ou na última sílaba, ou logo antes de `z`. (Uma excepção é *irmãmente*.)

O som mais parecido com o ditongo `ão` é `ã`, também escrito `an` ou `am`. Antes de `p` ou `b`, [é `am` e não `an`.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/412/112) Então, *tão + pouco = t**amp**ouco* é a grafia lógica para conformar ao padrão das outras palavras de português.

Comment: Acho que responde a pergunta do AP, mas me deixa com outra: *por que* usar uma junção de `tão` e `pouco` para dizer *também não*. Claro que o significado pode ter sido *bem* diferente muito tempo atrás, mas seria interessante entender também - o por quê que se usa essa palavra nesse sentido.

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar acrescentei uma comparação com outras palavras. Quanto a história do uso, não sei e não consigui encontrar nada.

Answer (score 6):

De acordo com o site [gramatica.net.br](http://www.gramatica.net.br/duvidas/tao-pouco-ou-tampouco/):

> É composto por uma junção de duas palavras que viraram apenas uma:
> “tão” e “pouco”

---

### Tão pouco

Essa expressão pode ser entendida como “muito pouco”, “pouca coisa”. É formada pelos Advérbios de intensidade “tão” e “pouco”. Normalmente é usado para expressar que algo foi realmente muito reduzido, escasso, curto. Para melhor entendimento do uso desta expressão veja alguns exemplos práticos:

> Eles ficaram tão pouco tempo.
>
> Não sabia que aqui tinha tão pouco espaço.
>
> você mostrou tão pouco interesse.

---

### Tampouco

Essa palavra é um advérbio, e funciona praticamente como o negativo de “também”. Pode ser facilmente substituído por “também não”, “nem” e “sequer”. É composto por uma junção de duas palavras que viraram apenas uma: “tão” e “pouco”. Não é a toa que a pronuncia seja tão parecida. A palavra é usada, praticamente, para reforçar alguma oração, frase ou expressão negativa já citada anteriormente. Veja alguns exemplos práticos para facilitar seu entendimento:

> Não gostei do filme, tampouco do cinema.
>
> Ela não me ama, tampouco me odeia.
>
> Se você não quer brigar, eu tampouco!